# Higher order derivate definition

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I know that higher-order derivatives are defined inductively as $f^{(n)}=(f^{n-1})'$.  However does this imply that 
$f^{(n)}(x) = \lim_{h\to0}\frac{f^{(n-1)}(x+h) - f^{(n-1)}(x)}{h}$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's precisely what it means.